# Android ndk r15b - Posix_memalign () undeclared identifier

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk

I am new to Android project. For my new task I need to build a project for Android platform.  I am able to generate make file successfully​ using `cmakelists.txt` for Android using Android ndk and it's corresponding `android.toolchain.cmake` file. When I tried to run `makefile`. I am facing:

> posix_memalign() undeclared identifier issue.

Here c and c++ compiler are clang which is default toolchain of Android ndk. I don't know how to fix this issue. Please help me to fix this issue.

I am using Windows os. I generated msys makefile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. 
stdlib is the header file needed for posix_memalign() function. Android ndk supports posix_memalign() function for the **ANDROID API** level above or equal to 16.
By adding -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=16 in cmake option , I was able to fix this issue.

Path: `/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h`

```
#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 16

int posix_memalign(void** memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size)  __INTRODUCED_IN(16);

#endif /* __ANDROID_API__ >= 16 */
```

Thanks !!!!

Comment: To be on the safe side, set `minSdkVersion` to `16`. I believe that cmake will inherit this, no need to additionally set `-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL`.

Comment: FYI the API level for `posix_memalign` was later moved from 16 to 17, so you’ll want to set your min API level accordingly: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/647